# When/how often does code run in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I'm just trying different things to learn how javascript works, and I'm wondering why the following doesn't work.

I've got a function that toggles `independent_color` between `"blue"` and `"red"` on button click:

```
$scope.independent_color = "blue";

$scope.toggle_independent_color = function() {
    if ($scope.independent_color == "blue") {
        $scope.independent_color = "red"
    }
    else {
        $scope.independent_color = "blue"
    }
}
```

Then, I have some conditionals that set `dependent_color` based on the value of `independent_color`:

```
if ($scope.independent_color == "blue") {
    $scope.dependent_color = "blue"
}

else {
    $scope.dependent_color = "red"
}
```

However, when I toggle `independent_color`, the value of `dependent_color` does not change.

Here's a FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/exr3tqm0/5/

My question is not how to get this to work. Rather, I'd like to know why it doesn't work. When/how often does the code run?

Comment: `When/how often does the browser check the conditional statements?` The question doesn't really make sense. The statements are check every time the code is run.

Comment: Never. But you need to read [ask] and fix your question before to get a better answer.

Comment: helps if you tag the framework you're using.

Comment: The browser runs the conditional when it executes the conditional. It does not remember if statements and just magically rerun them. If the value is changed, you need to trigger something that will rerun the code block.

Comment: in the case of your example, it is more specific to angular than javascript in general

Comment: @nem Please cut me some slack if I don't phrase my question correctly, I'm clearly confused. "When/how often does the code run?"

Comment: @aw04 Not really, this is a very general situation which just happens to be in an angular app. His code only runs once and he is expecting it to magically listen to changes.

Comment: @Roope Some of the code runs once when the angular controller is created and some if it runs on click because a function is bound to the angular controller scope, so I would say it is very much tied to angular. Having said that, it could be explained in a general way.

Comment: My question is, do you have any programming experience e.g. in other languages? Since this is a very basic general programming thing that is in no way specific to javascript. The same would happen in all other languages as well.

Comment: @Roope I appreciate your help. Learning javascript is my first programming experience. I understand it's a general programming thing, I'm just not sure what question to google to get a general understanding.

Comment: @aw04 I see what you mean. But if you can exclude all the angular parts of the code and the same exact problem would still remain, then how is it related to angular? Other than just happening to be inside an angular controller. It would be equivalent to just loading a JS file with the same contents, except for variable names of course. But anyway, an irrelevant side conversation, at least the problem is very basic.

Comment: @Roope Well I do agree with the part about this being a pointless side conversation :) Seriously though, I do see your point.. just depends on how you explain the problem

Answer (score 3):

It does not change because this code:

```
if ($scope.independent_color == "blue") {
    $scope.dependent_color = "blue"
}

else {
    $scope.dependent_color = "red"
}
```

lies directly in controller function, so it's executed only once, when controller is created (when you enter the view). Simply change your `dependantColor` in `toggle_independent_color`. You can also handle this dependency using angular's `$scope.watch` but it's not needed in your case.

Comment: And, I'll add, the toggle function works as expected because it is registered on the $scope when the controller is created and then tied to the view with the ng-click directive that angular provides. If this is one of your first ventures into JavaScript and browser coding, using the AngularJS framework might introduce more trouble and confusion than help. I recommend starting without a framework to learn the capabilities and build a strong foundation with the core language.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs once. The function for `toggle_independent_color` runs as many times as you click (your fiddle shows it attached via ng-click). All the other code runs once when your controller is instantiated. If you instantiate your controller multiple times (such as in having multiple of the same views) then it will run that many times, but each instantiated controller will have its own child scope.

On a side note, to get it to work, you can try putting that `dependent_color` functionality into another function.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

$scope.independent_color = "blue";

$scope.toggle_independent_color = function() {
    if ($scope.independent_color == "blue") {
        $scope.independent_color = "red"
    }
    else {
        $scope.independent_color = "blue"
    }
    checkDependent(); // check the dependent color when the button is clicked
}

// this check needs to be run each time the color is changed
function checkDependent(){
  if ($scope.independent_color == "blue") {
      $scope.dependent_color = "blue"
  }
  else {
      $scope.dependent_color = "red"
  }
}

}]);
```

Comment: @aw04, you're right, though showing how to get it to work helps us understand why something doesn't work. Will revise my answer

Comment: Sure but I think it needed the explanation as well to answer the question. Looks good after the edit